# Break table.rows().iterator() in DataTable in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to break DataTable() interations.
Here is my code

```
            let allCheckboxChecked=true;
            let table = $('#myTable').DataTable();           
            table.rows().iterator( 'row', function ( context, index ) {
                if($(this.row(index).node()).find("input").is(":Checked")){
                    allCheckboxChecked=true;
                }
                else{
                    allCheckboxChecked=false;
                    **return true;**    // This is not working...I want your help here
                }
            } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `nodes()` instead of `iterator()`

```
table.rows().nodes().to$().find('input:not(:checked):first').length // 0 - all checked
```

or with `each()`

```
let allCheckboxChecked = true;
table.rows().nodes().to$().each(function () {
    if (!$(this).find('input').is(':checked')) {
        allCheckboxChecked = false;
        return false;
    }
})
```